# How to add 'Add directory entries' in maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, dependency-injection

So I have a war file : app.war

inside app.war, i have a data-access.jar that contains my appcontext.xml which has the following declarations:

```
<bean id="Dao" class="com.test.www"/>
<bean id="DaoDependency" class="com.inner.www"/>
```

Dao in this case is inside a jar file (data-access.jar), now for the dao to work it needs to inject DaoDependecy which is in another jar! (data-access-dependency.jar).

When I run the application as a Java application, it works fine, however when i run through the war file, ie deployed in an application server, the dependencies field, I tried @Resources @Autowire, declaring the bean manually in xml i.e container the constructor:

```
<bean id="Dao" class="com.test.www">
        <property name="DaoDependency" ref="DaoDependency" />
    </bean>
```

In conclusion:

so I have this

dao.jar --> daodependency.jar - dependency injection works fine

app.war --> dao.jar --> daodependency.jar - FAIL!

UPDATE: I access the dao through:

```
@Autowired
Dao dao;
```

and tried

```
@Resource(name="dao")
Dao dao;
```

both returns null.

Please help, i'm limited to the structure of the application.

**UPDATE:**
`<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.www.*,com.inner.www.*"/>`

```
 I/O failure during classpath scanning; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: \deploymentfolder\app.war\WEB-INF\lib\dao.jar\com\test\www (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

jar files is there, I'm not using eclipse to export jar. using maven. 'Add directory entries'. I'm assuming this is the problem based on the other questions

Comment: What error do you get? As far as I can tell Spring should not have any issues with the above. As long as the jars are in the classpath / war it can handle injecting beans from multiple jars.

Comment: @John B both the dependency and dao returns null. No error.

Comment: what do you mean by "returns null"? How are you attempting to access them?

Comment: @John B i dao dependency is set to dao.jar's pom.xml and app.warhas dao.jar in its pom.xml. im tried accessing through autowiring and resource annotation doesnt work. Tried through initializing the appcontext. But dao dependency is missing.

Comment: could you provide the actual error message and also how have you configured the .war (the manifests)? additionally, which application server are you using?

Comment: @eis just posted the error

Comment: ok. could you add application server info and your .war manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I forgot to update my web.xml to configure Spring Context Listener. So it was working when running as a java application but not as a Web Application.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
        <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
```